# About the OR ( || ) Operator and return statements

Tags: c++, operators

I've been wondering, if i have a function like:

```
bool Foo::Bar()
{
     return A() || B() || C();
}
```

If A() returns true, would Bar() imediately return true or would it still calculate the results of B() and C() before evaluating the final value?

Comment: maybe lazy calculations?

Comment: Logical operators will short-circuit, so if A() is true, B() and C() will not be evaluated. This effect is commonly used to test something is null or not before dereference it. If you want to force evaluation, use bitwise operator.

Comment: @nhahtdh The bitwise operator has completely different semantics.  If you want to force evaluation, assign the results to a variable, and use that in the `||` expression.

Comment: @JamesKanze: On the hindsight, that's true, especially for `&&` vs. `&`. For `||` and `|`, I think there shouldn't be any problem if all the function returns int and similar types.

Comment: @nhahtdh It will probably work with `||` and `|`, but the semantics remain different.  I find it clearer to use the extra variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `A()` is true, neither B nor C will be evaluated. This is called [operator short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Similarly, in a statement such as `A && B && C`, if `A` is *false*, neither B or C will be evaluated.

This is not just an optimization; it is especially useful when `B` or `C` depend on `A`. For example, you can both test that a pointer *points* to something and invoke a method on the object being pointed to in a single statement:

```
if (my_pointer && my_pointer->some_method() > 9) {

}
```

Comment: [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: whether it is an optimization depends on some things (and of course the definition of `optimization`). To implement short-circuiting in the general case, the compiler has to emit branching structures, which might be less optimal than bitwise combinations.

Comment: @phresnel It's an optimization of source code size:-).  Or perhaps even programmer effort.  The generated code will probably be identical.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `Bar` would immediately return `true`, without calling `B` or `C`, because `||` is a [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operator. Same goes for the `&&` operator when its operands return `false`: the chain stops as soon as the result of the evaluation is known. This is essential in situations when the first part of the expression protects the second part from potential errors, like this:

```
return (ptr == NULL) || ptr -> failed();
```

If the evaluation did not stop after discovering that the initial part of the expression is `true`, a `NULL` pointer would be dereferenced in the second part, resulting in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> If A() returns true, would Bar() imediately return true or would it still calculate the results of B() and C() before evaluating the final value?

Nope!! It won't be executed at all iff `A()` return `true`.

The moment any operand of `||` operator returns true, further operands are not evaluated cause the result of the full expression is already known.